# Python convert *args to list

Tags: python, list, args

I am trying to learn how to use *args and came up with this.

```
alist =[5,2,6,1,2]
blist =[1,5,2,4,1]

def argstest(var1, var2, *args):
    print "var1", var1
    print "var2", var2

    temp = list(args)[0]

    for i in temp:
        if i > 3:
           print i

argstest(5, 8, alist, blist)
>>>>> var1 5
>>>>> var2 8
>>>>> 5
>>>>>>6
>>>>>>5
>>>>>>4
```

Though I see how this could be very useful my first concern was that

```
temp = list(args)[0]
```

is a very odd way to convert `*args` into a list, and the second was that this is not a standard way of making use of `*args`.

My question what would be the standard way of converting `*args` to a list?

Also, is this even the correct way to write a function that performs a task in this manner?

Comment: `*args` is a tuple, why do you need to convert it to a list? You are also passing *in* a list as one argument, so `args[0]` is that list.

Comment: Martijn, In the case of this function it has to be a list to iterate in the for loop.  

femtoRgon, these questions may be similar but they are not at all the same.

Comment: @NickSimas: No it doesn't. You can iterate a tuple, or in fact _any_ kind of iterable, exactly the same way you can iterate a list.

Comment: Meanwhile, why do you think calling `list` on something is "a very odd way to convert [it] to a list"? That's the standard, obvious way to convert anything to a list.

Comment: @NickSimas: a `for` loop takes any iterable; list or tuple makes no odds here.

Comment: On top of that, you're not actually iterating the list anyway, you're just indexing it with `[0]`. Which _also_ works exactly as well on a tuple, or any other kind of sequence, as on a list.

Comment: @NickSimas: your confusion probably stems from mixing `*args` syntax *and* passing in a list object. Now you have a list inside of a tuple. Try calling your function with `argstest(1, 2, 3, 4)` and see what happens to `args`.

Comment: Also, try adding `print args` in your function before calling it in various different ways.

Comment: Does *args essentially do the same things as if I were to put alist and blist inside a list and then call the function as: for i in list[alist,blist]: argtest(i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterates through each argument after the first two:

```
alist =[5,2,6,1,2]
blist =[1,5,2,4,1]

def argstest(*args):
    for i in args[2:]
        for j in i:
            if j > 3:
                print j

argstest(5, 8, alist, blist)
```

You'll see that *args allows you to pass in an arbitrary number of arguments. Now it flattens multiple lists into one.

Comment: Please clarify, this code doesn't work assuming you are still using the alist, blist.

Comment: Clearly the question has been updated since I wrote the answer, but since both lists are longer than 3, they are both printed by the loop.

Comment: @NickSimas did you want to convert both lists into a single list?

Comment: I wanted to iterate through both lists and perform some operation on each value, ie. in this case the operation is print.

Comment: @NickSimas this is an alternate way of iterating through each of the lists.

Answer (score 0):

You dont convert args into a list... args is a tupl and the first element is your list. Args is already a tupl. Just give the list to the function. You dont need to use the *.

Comment: I meant to infer that in this case there could be multiple lists or even a list of lists. But you're right I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

'*' combines all the unnamed parameters into tuple and such is *args. You should also look into **args (writing args is just a convention) which converts all named parameters into dictionaries. This is a step towards crossing between beginners to intermediate programmers. These two things will be widely used when you do OOP and use inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the temp variable just iterate through the args and print out each list.

```
alist =[5,2,6,1,2]
blist =[1,5,2,4,1]

def argstest(var1, var2, *args):
    print "var1", var1
    print "var2", var2

    for i in args:
        if i > 3:
           print i

argstest(5, 8, alist, blist)
```

Comment: That doesn't work, you can't iterate through tuples with for i in

Comment: your code prints as var1 5
var2 8
[5, 2, 6, 1, 2]
[1, 5, 2, 4, 1]

Comment: @NickSimas nonsense. As Martijn already pointed out above, `for` takes *any* iterable: list, tuple, generator...

Comment: Then why am I getting  [5, 2, 6, 1, 2] [1, 5, 2, 4, 1] ??